# Safely replace a packaged Master-Detail with Lookup

Tags: lookup, data, master-detail, locking, data-skew

My active 1GP Managed Package app suffers from Account and **Data skew** (with ROW LOCKING) because we made a custom object `AccountItem__c` a child in a Master-Detail relation (MDR) ship with `Account`.

As Salesforce seems not to be able to convert this field type I thought of another approach and would like to hear you opinion. Is this a good idea? Are there others? Better alternatives?

**Major Release 1**

1. Package a Lookup from `AccountItem__c` to `Account`
2. Package a Migration script that copies over from Master Detail to Lookup
3. Great Major release and upgrade all subscribers

**Major Release 2**

3. Adjust packaged code to use Lookup instead and ignore MDR
4. [Remove the MDR field from the package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sac0mNYqovw)
5. Great Major release and upgrade all subscribers

---

5. Tell customers to delete the field also in their subscriber orgs
6. Adress issues where customer customizations rely on deprecated field

Is that too simplistic?

Comment: *Package a Migration script that copies over from Master Detail to Lookup* -- that can be a weak point if there are any custom development (validation rules, triggers, integrations etc) attached to the account item. That data migration process might require an overview (I was doing similar things manually for all package subscribers, but due to low amount of subscribers it was not that time-consuming)

Comment: Refer this article https://www.mirketa.com/replacing-a-master-detail-field-in-a-salesforce-managed-package/